# проблема с функциями str_split и implode

Tags: php

Здраствуйте. У меня проблема с кодом.

```
<?php
$login = "SELECT * FROM users";
$loogin = str_split($login, 1); 
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($login); $i++) {
    if($i % 2 == 0 && $i != 0) {
        $loogin[$i] = " ";
    }
}
                 
$swses = implode(NULL, $loogin);             
echo "SE E T * F O s r " . "<br>" . $swses;
if ($swses == "SE E T * F O s r ") {
    echo "SE E T * F O s r " . "<br>" . $swses;
}
?>
```

Проблема в том, что if в конце проверяет не переменную $swses , а переменную $login

Comment: if  в конце не может проверять $login, потому что там переменная $swses. Покажите вывод прогаммы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас условие if не выполняется лишь по той причине, что `$swses` не может получиться `SE E T * F O s r` . Оно получается `SE E T * F O   s r` .

```
SE E T * F O s r 
SE E T * F O   s r
```

Видите разницу?

Comment: У меня почему-то $swses получается SE E T * F O s r сейчас попробую, то , что вы написали

Comment: Да. Вы правы, только не пойму почему у меня выдает SE E T * F O s r
SE E T * F O s r

Comment: Потому что Html вырезает лишние пробелы. Попробуйте перед выводом передать заголовок `Content-Type: text/plain` и `"<br>"` замените на `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: @MishaOleinik если ответ решил вашу проблему, отметьте пожалуйста его как верный и закройте вопрос